# How to get the reduction in Heat Flux due to Barbecue Roll on Spacecraft?

Tags: spacecraft, thermal, thermal-control, heat

As we know, to keep the surface of the spacecraft relatively cool, we spin the spacecraft so that not just one side of the spacecraft is heated.
Due to this what is the effective Heat Flux encountered by the spacecraft?

Comment: The barbecue roll results in a better distribution of heat. If all sides of the spacecraft use the same material, the heat input is not affected.

Comment: slightly related [Why does JWST need "a carefully designed series of oscillations" to avoid overheating during the 2nd stage burn? Why not rotate "rotisserie style"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57344/12102)

Comment: So if the spacecraft is receiving X W/m2 of heat flux from one direction and it has a curved surface of 2 m2 so one side would be 1 m2. So would the net incoming heat be simply X W? and would the barbecue roll not affect anything at all ( except heat distribution)?